# Is the product of uniquely decipherable codes uniquely decipherable?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

A code $C$ is *prefix-free* if no codeword in $C$ is a prefix of another codeword in $C$. For example, $C=\{0,10,110\}$ is prefix-free but $D=\{0,10,100\}$ is not.

A code $C$ is *uniquely decipherable* if given any combination of codewords in $C$ there is a unique way to decipher it. For example, $C=\{0,011,101 \}$ is uniquely decipherable but $D=\{010,10,101\}$ is not.

The product of codes $C$ and $D$ is the set $C \times D = \{ cd : c \in  C\ and\ d \in D \}$

It is also known that prefix-free implies uniquely decipherable, but the converse is false. 
I've proved that the product of prefix-free code is prefix-free, so it would imply that the product of prefix-free code is uniquely decipherable.

I'm pretty sure the answer to the  question is no, but I still cannot find any counter-examples.

Comment: What do you mean by the _product_ of $C$?

Comment: C1xC2={c1c2 : c1 in C1 and c2 in C2}

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch is right. Consider this case
$A = {0, 10, 11}$ and $B = {1,00, 10}$ (B is the reverse of a prefix free)
Now
$A \times B = {01,000,010,101,111,1000,1010,1100,1110}$.

There should be easier ones as well but this is what I got,

01 010 101 01

010 1010 101